# How to get yesterday date and stored into one variable

Tags: shell, date, hp-ux

I am having a log file where I need to grep based on yesterday date. How to get the yesterday date.

The time stamp in the log file is formatted as:

- `Wed Sep 23` for two digit
- `Wed Dec  1` for one digit

Note that I'm on HP/UX where `date` is not GNU `date`.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you could use perl

```
$ dt=`perl -e 'print substr(scalar localtime(time-86400),0,10)'`
$ echo "$dt"
Sat Dec  5
$ grep "$dt" <logfile>
```

In the `perl` code above, `time` returns the current time in seconds since epoch. To get yesterday, subtracting 86400 seconds and scalar prints it in human readable format. I assume you just need yesterday in `DAY MON DT` format, so you could grep all lines matching that day, irrespective of time. To just grab required fields, using `substr` to print the first 10 characters and saving in `dt` variable. You could use that variable with `grep`.

Comment: Note that in timezones that do daylight-saving, there's one hour every year during which that doesn't work properly.

Comment: I don't want to use perl . is their any another alternative

Comment: @Pooja Is `C` an option? will you be able to compile small piece of code to print yesterday (or) Does your `awk` support `systime` and `strftime` ? if so you could try `echo | awk '{print strftime("%a %b %e",systime()-86400);}'`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly worded, but from what I gathered you're looking for something like this:

```
date --date="-1 day" +"%a %b %-d"
```

This will give you yesterdays date formatted in the same way you gave in your log file snippet. You can save this to a variable by doing:

```
yesterday=$(date --date="-1 day" +"%a %b %-d")
```

or to grep you can do something like the following:

```
yesterday=$(date --date="-1 day" +"%a %b %-d") ; grep "$yesterday" <file name>
```

I hope that answers your question

Comment: it doesn't support . I don't have gnu . I am using HP-UX. It's showing illegal options

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't know HP-UX or have a system of it to test on. You'll want to take a look at the man page for date on your system and try to replicate my solution or a similar one, its likely it will be a similar process just different flags are used etc

Comment: It does not allow to take as -1 day . I also tried but it didn't work @bevreti